# If Statement with Empty _Get

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I am busy learning PHP. However doing a small website with PHP where I control the Variables passed, I am stuck at a If statement issue.

Every internal page link I have passes a variable to control the content I pull from a database. even links from other internal pages to my Index.php page. The thing is the index.php page gives errors because there is a empty _Get issue when you enter the saite from external link. There are four pages. all other pages work with no errors but loading index page gives error.

My code:

```
$Section = $_GET['SID'];
if ( $Section == "HOME" ) {
    $SectionTitle = 'Start';
    $SectionID = 'HOME';
}
if ( $Section == "BDIR" ) {
    $SectionTitle = 'Directory';
    $SectionID = 'BDIR';
}
if ( $Section == "ACOM" ) {
    $SectionTitle = 'Accommodation';
    $SectionID = 'ACOM';
}
if ( $Section == "REST" ) {
    $SectionTitle = 'Restaurants';
    $SectionID = 'REST';
}
```

What I need to achieve is when there is an empty _Get its must assign the same value as the Home (First If) Values.

I have tried

```
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $SectionTitle = 'Start';
    $SectionID = 'HOME';
}
```

and a few other variations with no luck.

But I think I am out of my league, as I wonder, should some if my statements not be within(under) other if statements here?

Comment: Consider switching to @EugeneSue's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32154803/66580). For a small number of branches mine is as good as his, but the approach he has taken is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Section = !isset($_GET['SID']) || empty($_GET['SID']) ? 'HOME' : $_GET['SID'];
switch($Section) {
  case "BDIR":
    $SectionTitle = 'Directory';
    $SectionID = 'BDIR';
    break;
  case "ACOM"
    $SectionTitle = 'Accommodation';
    $SectionID = 'ACOM';
    break;
  case "REST":
    $SectionTitle = 'Restaurants';
    $SectionID = 'REST';
    break;
  case "HOME":
  default:
    $SectionTitle = 'Start';
    $SectionID = 'HOME';
    break;
}
```

Comment: perfect... it is working now ! Please explain the working if the first line ? the rest i understand! its just the first line dont make sense

Comment: @Cavemanharris In the first line we check if `$_GET['SID']` is NOT defined (URL missing `SID`), *OR* is `empty` and in both cases we assign `HOME` to `$Section`, otherwise, we just read that parameter into `$Section`.

Answer (score 2):

In order not to write many similar if-statements i'd rather add an array and check it by key presence.
Then define default SectionTitle and SectionID like this:

```
<?php

$SectionTitle = 'Start';
$SectionID    = 'HOME';

$sections = [
    'BDIR' => 'Directory', 
    'ACOM' => 'Accommodation',
    'REST' => 'Restaurants'
];

if (!empty($_GET['SID']) && array_key_exists($_GET['SID'], $sections)) {
    $SectionTitle = $sections[$_GET['SID']];
    $SectionID    = $_GET['SID'];
}
```

Comment: This keeps the business logic closer together. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you. try this code.

```
 if($_GET)
{
    $Section = $_GET['SID'];
    if ( $Section == "HOME" ) {
        $SectionTitle = 'Start';
        $SectionID = 'HOME';
    }
    if ( $Section == "BDIR" ) {
        $SectionTitle = 'Directory';
        $SectionID = 'BDIR';
    }
    if ( $Section == "ACOM" ) {
        $SectionTitle = 'Accommodation';
        $SectionID = 'ACOM';
    }
    if ( $Section == "REST" ) {
        $SectionTitle = 'Restaurants';
        $SectionID = 'REST';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your Answers. i manages to get the one from Majid Fouladpour working.